# nohup multiple sequential commands not logging output

Tags: logging, python, remote, nohup

I have a python script (which takes a lot of time to complete the execution) that I need to run several times varying the parameters. And it's executed in a remote machine. For instance and test purposes, take the following script `test.py`:

```
import time

print("\nStart time: {}".format(time.ctime()))
time.sleep(10)
print("End time: {}".format(time.ctime()))
```

For this I normaly use `nohup`. It's work just fine whith one execution using the following command:

```
nohup test.py &
```

The outputs are correctly saved in `nohup.out` file. To run in sequence I've done some research and found [this question][1] and I came up with the following command:

```
nohup $(python test.py; python test.py) &
```

Which works fine. I run the command, quickly logged out and in again and saw through `htop` the first execution running, then finishing and then the second one starting. But the problem is that the output isn't been saved into `nohup.out` file. If I wait in terminal for both executions to finish, the following error is showed:

> nohup: failed to run command 'Start': No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong here?

**PS.:**
I need to log the outputs because I need to see the current progress of the script and know which error happened if it doesn't finish properly. So if there is some other command to use instead of `nohup` which could log python `print`'s it will be welcomed too.

Comment: "And it's executed in a remote machine." : have a look at Fabric: https://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: Very interesting @PatrickMevzek. But for my case the scripts take a very long time and I don't want to have my local machine on all this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(...)` is resolved first, only then `nohup`. I.e. when you run `nohup $(python test.py; python test.py) &` this is what happens:

1. The shell runs `$(...)` which returns string `Start time ...` and then
2. Runs `nohup Start time ...` which obviously fails because there is no such command `Start`.

Since `nohup` only can run one command this is a common workaround:

```
~ $ nohup sh -c "python test.py; python test.py" &
```

So you run `sh` in `nohup` and it then executes the commands you want.